# Add a UIView to a UIViewController with Xib

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

Here is what i am trying to do:

1. I have `AViewController` and it's Xib, then I add a `UIView` half the screen which I connect this view to B-UIView and B-UIView has its own xib where i do the design.

In other words I have a view controller with it's view which becomes the "mainview" as I add other views to it which come with its own xibs.

Hierarchy:

1 `ViewController` UIView (xib) 
    2.B-UIView (has its own xib)
    3.C-UIView (has its own xib)

So is this possible if so how?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do this and it's not difficult at all!

In fact, it's a pretty common way to design something in Interface Builder. You can then load your custom Xib file programmatically using `loadNibNamed`. For example:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TVCell" owner:self options:nil];
```

Apple's docs talk about this in the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Although their example is about creating a custom table cell, the same rules apply for any view. Have a close look at the section entitled [Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7).

One thing they don't do in that example is to load the top level view. `loadNibNamed` returns an array, so to get that top level view that you're after, you should also do:

```
   MyCustomView *myCustomView = [myNibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

So, your code will look like:

```
   NSArray *myNibsArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil];
   MyCustomView *myCustomView = [myNibsArray objectAtIndex:0];
```